# How does this example of passing environment variables in linux to node work?

Tags: node.js, linux, environment-variables

I read and verified that I can pass environment variables to node by doing something like:

```
MY_ENV_VAR1=/tmp MY_ENV_VAR2=/data node index.js
```

How on earth does that work? I've only seen arguments to a script come after the script name, not before.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the standard way of defining and passing on the environment variables to a particular command from a Linux shell w/o exporting it.

More details: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158117/how-to-pass-environment-variables-to-a-non-interactive-shell-with-example